# OAuth2 flow with Authorization Code grant type in SPA and Spring Boot Rest Api application

Tags: spring-boot, security, oauth-2.0, jwt, openid-connect

I have read dozens of articles and inspect lots of projects on Github about OAuth2 with authorization code grant type but still think that I have some mistakes about it.

I have the following scenario for showing the case:

Front-end SPA application ( React )

- In this application user will login with her github credentials and I will list his repositories and some other information from github.
- Back-end Spring Boot: Will make github api calls and returns response to the fe client

My flow:

1-) User clicks login with github button and redireted to github: https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&redirect_uri=http:localhost:8080/oauth/callback/github

2-) User authorized the client and redirected to BE Spring Boot application with code. With this code it exchange with an access token

3-) In this section BE Spring Boot gets the access token and sends it to the FE React Application

4-) For interactin with github, like listing repositories and other actions FE Sends access token to BE and be calls github with the token and returns response to the FE Application

For me this is the flow but I have doubt about the 3rd and 4th stepms. FE needs to store the access token in somewhere like cookie or local stage so It might be not secure. If I don't send access token to the FE how BE knows about the access token to make call so Be must be stateless at this point.

What I'm missing ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If your Spring Boot App is stateful, you can keep the access token in the Backend (e.g. in a database) and tie it to a session id. The frontend client will only have a session cookie and call the backend with that cookie. Spring will lookup the Github access token in the db and make a call to github.

If you don't want to have a database then the only way is to keep the token in the frontend, either in a cookie or in memory. Then send the token to the backend with every request.

I would rather avoid keeping the access token in the local storage - either memory or a http-only cookie.

Every solution has it's pros and cons, and there are different attack vectors that you must take into consideration. E.g. when you keep tokens in the backend you have to think more about csrf and session riding.

Have a look at this article we wrote at Curity which outlines some [best practices for SPAs and OAuth](https://curity.io/resources/learn/spa-best-practices/).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have read in one article that they store access and refresh token in BE ( in DB ) but store it encripted. Then they send encription key to the fe and store it in cookie. Every time new request comes to the BE, they fetch the encrypted access token from db, and decrypt it with the key and use it. Do you think this approach is feasible ? and do you think whether it protects me from csrf and session riding ?

Comment: Unfortunately no, it doesn't. It protects you from someone reading the contents of the cookie. So even if the attacker manages to intercept such cookie, they won't be able to extract the value of the token from it and use the token offline. They can still do anything that can be done with a cookie (so send requests exactly as the user would).

Comment: `Then they send encription key to the fe and store it in cookie` - I think the encrypted token is stored in the cookie, not the encryption key. The encryption key should be kept safe by the backend, it shouldn't be released to the frontend.

Comment: I have read the sections in Curity but stil confused how to do it. What is your suggestion for doing that ?